# What is the difference between CAN-C and CAN-IHS buses?

Tags: jeep, can-bus, cherokee

When talking about a 2014 Jeep Cherokee, what is the difference between CAN-C and CAN-IHS buses?

Comment: There are two PDF's which will probably help you tremendously here. Since you specify the 2014 Jeep Cherokee and wondering about the CAN-Bus, I'm assuming you are wondering about the hack which was done by Chris Valasek and Charlie Miller. I found their white papers which spells a lot of this out. You can find them [here](http://www.ioactive.com/pdfs/IOActive_Remote_Attack_Surfaces.pdf) and [here](http://www.ioactive.com/pdfs/IOActive_Remote_Car_Hacking.pdf). The first one contains a bit of the info of the second, but you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CAN-C is the high speed bus that connects the engine, brakes, airbags etc. CAN-IHS is a low speed bus that connects the comfort systems like radio and climate controls.

Comment: I though HS stands for High Speed...